# Module object not callable in sleep if conditional ( python )

Tags: python, import

I have imported the following modules at the top of my python script:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import random
import pprint
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

But, I am still getting a module object error for this part of my code:

```
def check(low,high):
    with open('done.txt', 'r+') as done:
        ts = time.time()
        sttime = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        done_completed = open('done_completed.txt', "a")
        for line in done:
            now = datetime.now()
            now_time = now.time()
            if now_time >= time(23,30) and now_time <= time(06,30):
                print "sleeping"
                sleep(5000)
            else:
                done_id = line.strip()[20:]
                then = datetime.strptime(line.strip()[:17], '%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

(There's another if elif elif under all that but I figured it isn't relevant to the error)

(Yes, I am a python beginner)

The error is:

```
  File "/home/joe/Desktop/follomatic/follomatic.py", line 85, in check
if now_time >= time(23,30) and now_time <= time(06,30):
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Does anyone see what is wrong? Have I not specified to call the module in the right way?

Thanks :)

Comment: `time` is a module, not a function. You probably meant `time.time()`.

Comment: Thanks grc - whereabouts in the code do you mean? now_time = time.time() instead of now_time = now.time() ?

Comment: In the line with the error, you have `time(23,30)` and `time(06,30)`. I'm not sure what you were intending, but this doesn't work since `time` is a module.

Comment: @grc: [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) takes no arguments. But [datetime.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.time#datetime.time) does. Not to be confused with [datetime.datetime.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.time#datetime.datetime.time). As I said in my answer, it's a bit of a rat's nest. :)

Comment: @joep1: Even if you fix the function calls up, this logic isn't going to work with `datetime.time`s : `if now_time >= time(23,30) and now_time <= time(06,30):` That test will never be `True`. You'd need something like `if now_time >= time(23,30) or now_time <= time(06,30):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `datetime` module is a bit of a rat's nest. :) And it can get even more confusing if you use `from` imports.

This code should clarify things a bit. Note that this is **not** a great way to do things. It's generally better to work with `datetime.datetime` objects rather than `datetime.time` objects, otherwise things get messy if you need to handle time intervals that include midnight (or multiple days). But I wrote this code to roughly correspond with the code in your question, and I wanted to make it easy to test at any time of day.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    ''' datetime.time manipulation demo

        From http://stackoverflow.com/q/28605732/4014959

        Written by PM 2Ring 2015.02.19
    '''

    from time import sleep
    import datetime

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_time = now.time()

    #A datetime.time example
    t1 = datetime.time(5, 30)
    print 't1 is', t1

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_time = now.time()
    print 'now is %s, now_time is %s' % (now, now_time)

    begin_datetime = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
    end_datetime = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

    begin_time = begin_datetime.time()
    end_time = end_datetime.time()

    print 'begin', begin_time
    print 'end', end_time

    for i in xrange(15):
        now_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        print now_time, begin_time <= now_time <= end_time
        sleep(1)
```

**typical output**

```
t1 is 05:30:00
now is 2015-02-19 23:44:39.152786, now_time is 23:44:39.152786
begin 23:44:44.152786
end 23:44:49.152786
23:44:39.152905 False
23:44:40.153999 False
23:44:41.155191 False
23:44:42.156398 False
23:44:43.156614 False
23:44:44.157810 True
23:44:45.159028 True
23:44:46.160231 True
23:44:47.161444 True
23:44:48.162660 True
23:44:49.163869 False
23:44:50.165076 False
23:44:51.166650 False
23:44:52.167842 False
23:44:53.169053 False
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to take me a while to get my head around this but it seems to work!

Comment: Weirdly, my code DOES work if you take it out of the with/for loops... I remembered where I got it originally from the top answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048249/how-do-i-determine-if-current-time-is-within-a-specified-range-using-pythons-da/10048290#10048290