# Python 2: Compare a timestamp between two points in time

Tags: python, python-datetime

For my script I need to use Python 2.6 with only the standard library. I am trying to write a script that walks a logs directory that has a condition defined that only matches the logs that have the appropriate timestamp. The timestamp I am using is derived from the filename. I do not want to use the OS timestamps because there are times the files get copied off to a different directory to prevent them from being overwritten and this changes the file modified time.

A new file gets created every 200MB. The timestamp on the filename is the time the file was created and represents the oldest log entry in the file.

```
import datetime

# One event might span multiple log files.
call_start = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 25, 9)
call_stop = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 37, 38)

# Timestamp values of file generated from file's naming convention
t1 = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 4, 48, 16)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 3, 53)
t3 = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 19, 14)
t4 = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 35)
t5 = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 5, 49, 19)

file_times = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]

matching_times = []
for ftime in file_times:
    # Logic I can't figure out
    if scratches_head:
        matching_times.append(ftime)

# I would expect the matching_times list to contain t3 and t4
```

---

**Edit**

Clarification from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400329/python-2-compare-a-timestamp-between-two-points-in-time/50400745#comment87816814_50400329):

`t3` is a file that was created at `5:19:14am`. The `call_start` is the first entry I would see in the log. It begins at `5:25:09am`. Since `t4` didn't get created until `5:35:00am`, the `call_start` has to be in `t3`. The `call_stop` is the last log entry I want to find. I would be in `t4` because `t5` was created at `5:49:19am`.

Comment: Why would t3 and t4 match? What are you trying to match on?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the logic. Do you want to find timestamps that happen in between `call_start` and `call_stop`? If so, I don't understand why `t3` here qualifies. See: [How to determine if a timestamp is within a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048249/how-do-i-determine-if-current-time-is-within-a-specified-range-using-pythons-da/10048290)

Comment: Whatever your rule is, just write the comparison and you're done. For example, `if call_start <= ftime < call_stop:` will tell you whether `ftime` is in between `call_start` and `call_stop`, just like `2 <= n < 5` will tell you whether `n` is between 2 and 5. And if you want a closed range instead of a half-open range, change the `<` to `<=`. And so on. (Of course all reasonable rules I can think of are only going to pass `t4`, but pault already covered that.)

Comment: t3 is a file that was created at 5:19:14am. The call_start is the first entry I would see in the log. It begins at 5:25:09am. Since t4 didn't get created until 5:35:00am, the call_start has to be in t3. The call_stop is the last log entry i want to find. I would be in t4 because t5 was created at 5:49:19am.

Comment: OK, so turn that logic into code: whenever `file_times[i] > call_start` but `file_times[i-1] >= call_start`, you want `file_times[i-1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `enumerate()` over the items in your list and create ranges from each consecutive pair of times. Then check to see if any of these [ranges overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/325964) with `(call_start, call_end)`. If the range overlaps, append the start of the range to your list. You'd also have to include in a special check for the last time in the list.

For example:

```
for i, ftime in enumerate(file_times):
    if i+1 >= len(file_times):
        # last item in list, add if it's less than call_stop
        scratches_head = ftime < call_stop
    else:
        # check if ranges overlap
        fstart = ftime
        fend = file_times[i+1]
        scratches_head = (fstart <= call_stop) and (fend >= call_start)

    if scratches_head:
        matching_times.append(ftime)

print([datetime.datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for x in matching_times])
#['2018-05-15 05:19:14', '2018-05-15 05:35:00']
```

Comment: I tried implementing this. On the example it works, but when i ran it against a big list of files it matches incorrectly. I can also get its match behavior to change if i do sorted(file_times).

Comment: @JeffA `file_times` in this example is already sorted- in fact, that is a requirement for this method to work. It assumes that consecutive entries form a range- this only works if the times are sorted. Can you [edit] your question and add an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine. The sort was the key to making it all work. When i first tested sorting i most not have done something correctly or misinterpreted the results. Thanks for the help.