# Creation of slots at regular intervals

Tags: python, django

I need to create time-slots according to a number of songs. For example, s if my playlist has 5 songs then we create the time-interval of slots by the logic, 60/5 = 12 minutes in this example as the number of songs was 5 here.

I also provide the start_time and end_time.
Here if I provide `start_time = 5:00 am and end_time = 6:00 am, total songs = 5`

```
S1: 5:00 - 5:12
S2: 5:12 - 5:24
S3: 5:24 - 5:36
S4: 5:36 - 5:48
S5: 5:48 - 6:00
```

The Model consists of these three fields:

```
class SlotCreate(models.Model):
  from_time = models.TimeField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  to_time = models.TimeField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')
  labelling = models.ForeignKey('Labelling',blank=True, null=True)
```

I am checking whether the slot exists with the following query:

```
SlotCreate.objects.filter(from_time=from_time,to_time=to_time,labelling=label).exists():
       errors.append("The Slot already exists "+"\n")
```

The problem here is if the user provides:

```
Start_time = 5:00
End_time = 6:00
Total songs = 3
```

Then the slots already exist in the time interval given above as S1, S2, S3, S4, S5 are already there. The piece of code with which I check above fails to determine this case as

```
S1: 5:00 - 5:20
S1: 5:20 - 5:40
S1: 5:40 - 6:00
```

Can anyone help me what am I missing here in the condition?

**Update 1:**

I have written the following query, but however, am unable to workout for values after mid-night. Can some-one please offer some help with below query so, that we can check whether the slots do not overlap and raise an error when overlapping.

```
SlotCreate.objects.filter(labelling = label).exclude((Q(from_time__gte=dateTimeA.time()) & Q(from_time__gte = dateTimeB.time())) | (Q(to_time__lte = dateTimeA.time()) & Q(to_time__lte = dateTimeB.time()))):
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine if any existing slot overlaps the range given by the user?  Your filter is doing an exact, but needs to use __gte and __lte on the times to check the range. If crossing midnight is a concern, you can use Q objects to create more sophisticated conditions.  Sometimes it helps to think about what your SQL would look like.

Comment: Yes, @JoeHolloway, I am determining if any existing slot overlaps the range given by the user. However, if you can suggest some-help for the query in update 1 when we consider midnight values also?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
timeA = dateTimeA.time()
timeB = dateTimeB.time()

label_filter = Q(labelling=label)
if timeA <= timeB:
    # Is either from_time OR to_time in the range?
    time_filter = Q(from_time__gte=timeA, from_time__lte=timeB)
    time_filter |= Q(to_time__gte=timeA, to_time__lte=timeB)
else:
    # Crosses midnight
    time_filter = (Q(from_time__gte=timeA) | Q(from_time__lte=timeB))
    time_filter |= (Q(to_time__gte=timeA) | Q(to_time__lte=timeB))

exists = SlotCreate.objects.filter(label_filter & time_filter).exists()
```

For the midnight condition, you basically just swap the values you're comparing against.  The `Q` object does an `AND` by default so you don't need extra Q objects to pull it off in the first condition.

Just a note, this obviously doesn't handle ranges larger than 24 hours, but your model doesn't support that if it's only storing time values.