# Return false if the current day is a saturday or a sunday

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to check two things:

1. If the time is between a specified interval.
2. And if the current day is a weekday.

I have found this code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048249/how-do-i-determine-if-current-time-is-within-a-specified-range-using-pythons-da/10048290?noredirect=1#comment115272969_10048290):

```
from datetime import datetime, time

def is_time_between(begin_time, end_time, check_time=None):
    # If check time is not given, default to current UTC time
    check_time = check_time or datetime.now().time() # datetime.utcnow().time()
    if begin_time < end_time:
        return check_time >= begin_time and check_time <= end_time
    else: # crosses midnight
        return check_time >= begin_time or check_time <= end_time
```

And it works fantastic!

But how to, regardless, return `false` if the day is on a saturday or sunday?

Comment: datetime.now().time() is a datetime.time object - which has no concept of day of the week. datetime.now() is a datetime.datetime object, which you can call the isoweekday() method on. If check_time is expecting a datetime.time object, there is no way of determining the day of week.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one more check of `check_time.weekday()>=5` as in:

from datetime import datetime, time

```
def is_time_between(begin_time, end_time, check_time=None):
    # If check time is not given, default to current UTC time
    check_time = check_time or datetime.now() # datetime.utcnow().time()
    if check_time.weekday()>=5:
        return False
    elif begin_time < end_time:
        return check_time >= begin_time and check_time <= end_time
    else: # crosses midnight
        return check_time >= begin_time or check_time <= end_time
```

P.S. To check for the weekday date information is vital which is not present in `datetime.now().time()`. You might want to use `datetime.now()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `weekday()` in order to retrieve the weekday of the given date. If it the returned value is 5 or 6 it means that it is saturday or sunday.

You can find more information here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday