# Python objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I was reading:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836918/15033009

I copied the solution like this:

```
    if is_now_in_time_period(datetime.time(7, 30), datetime.time(23, 59), datetime.datetime.now().time()):
        print('hi')
```

But python gives me an error:

> PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 207, in main
> if is_now_in_time_period(datetime.time(7, 30), datetime.time(23, 59), datetime.datetime.now().time()): TypeError: descriptor 'time' for
> 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: Is the solution not working any more?

Comment: should be `is_now_in_time_period(time(7, 30), time(23, 59),datetime.now().time()):
`

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: what is your `is_now_in_time()` ??

Comment: What does your import look like? it should be `import datetime`

Comment: I have: from datetime import datetime

Comment: Check my answer. Are you doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
import datetime as dt

def is_time_between(begin_time, end_time, check_time=None):
    # If check time is not given, default to current UTC time
    check_time = check_time or dt.datetime.utcnow().time()
    if begin_time < end_time:
        return check_time >= begin_time and check_time <= end_time
    else: # crosses midnight
        return check_time >= begin_time or check_time <= end_time

if is_time_between(dt.time(7, 30), dt.time(23, 59),dt.datetime.now().time()):
    print('hi')
```

---

```
hi
```

Comment: I have another line which won't work after changing import:             start_time = time.time()