# Is there a date/year function in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

how do i write a code that notifies me that a certificate is valid from 17 March 2017 to 16 March 2022 and should be renewed from 17 March 2022 for another validity period of 5 years. Please note that the standard validity period is usually 5 years.

I put together some code on jupyter notebook using python which I ran and got an output as shown in the attached image, I however feel I however know it has not been done right.

find my codes below:

[code sample used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uubl.png)

Comment: May be this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048249/how-do-i-determine-if-current-time-is-within-a-specified-range-using-pythons-da

Answer (score 2):

Note that you should post your code as code sample and not as a picture so people have more time to solve your problem than reconstructing your problem.

A solution could be `datetime` and `relativedelta`.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def time_in_range(start, end, current):

    if start <= current <= end:
        print("Ticket valid")
    else:
        print("Ticket invalid")


start = datetime.date(2015, 1, 30)
end = start + relativedelta(years=5)
current = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

This way you can check if a date is in a given range.

Comment: Thank you very much Broxy.  Your response, input and suggestion to append my code as a sample rather than an image is very well received. I will definitely keep that in mind. I joined stack flow today. Still familiarizing myself with it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime function of python. Read this [Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you Moshiur Rahman Faisal. Much appreciated.